# Do you still need to convert video for iPhone 4 (and now iPod Touch)

Tags: ipod-touch, video, ios

Short of the filetype (alot of what I have I don't believe is supported by either device) Do I need to convert movies specifically for them? Or can I load them as is?

Answer (score 2):

iTunes will convert some file types for you. For those you want to convert yourself (custom resolution, bitrate, etc) I like to use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). I'm also experimenting (right this moment actually lol) with [AVIDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/).

But to answer your question, I guess it depends on what the original file type is. Here is the spec sheet from [Apple](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html).

> Video formats supported: H.264 video
>   up to 720p, 30 frames per second, Main
>   Profile level 3.1 with AAC-LC audio up
>   to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in
>   .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;
>   MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by
>   480 pixels, 30 frames per second,
>   Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to
>   160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo
>   audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file
>   formats; Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35
>   Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames
>   per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo
>   audio in .avi file format

Answer (score 1):

Try an app called [OPlayer](http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/oplayer/id344784375?mt=8). It plays just about anything, straight from a webserver or  iTunes file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

#### [PunyVid](http://www.smallsoftware.co.uk/site/C21/)

Converts videos specifically for iPhone/iPod.

Answer (score 0):

There is an iphone-app called yxplayer that can play many more video formats than are supported natively by iTunes/iPod/iPhone. However, playback often judders, the UI is quite minimalistic, and it does not remember last playback position etc.